# Neighborhood base of weak topology

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

If $X$ is a Banach space, the weak topology on $X$ is the weakest topology in which each functional $f$ in $X^\ast$ is continuous.

I have some difficulties in understanding its neighborhood basis in 0.

It should be made by the sets of the form

$N(f_1,...,f_n;\epsilon)=\{x :|f_i(x)|<\epsilon, \text{for }i=1,\dots,n\}$
for each finite $n$.

I don't understand why is this a neighborhood basis and not simply $N(f;\epsilon)=\{x : |f(x)|<\epsilon\}$.

Can you explain to me this as clearly as you can? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A neighbourhood basis of a point $x$ in a topological space is a family $\mathscr{B}_x$ of neighbourhoods of $x$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains some member of $\mathscr{B}_x$. In particular, since the intersection of finitely many neighbourhoods of $x$ is again a neighbourhood of $x$, we must for every pair $V,W\in \mathscr{B}_x$ have an $U\in \mathscr{B}_x$ with $U \subset V\cap W$.

The intersection $N(f;\epsilon_1) \cap N(g;\epsilon_2)$ does in general not contain any set of the form $N(h;\epsilon_3)$, since for $f,g$ linearly independent, $N(f,\epsilon_1)\cap N(g;\epsilon_2)$ contains a linear subspace of codimension $2$, but no linear subspace of codimension $1$, while $N(h;\epsilon)$ contains a linear subspace of codimension $\leqslant 1$ (the kernel of $h$).

So we need to take finite intersections in order to have a neighbourhood-basis element contained in the intersection of two neighbourhood-basis elements.

The sets $N(f;\epsilon)$ form a neighbourhood-subbasis, however.

Comment: Hi Daniel. It's a great solution, but may I ask how I could directly see that each $N(f_1, \dotsb, f_n;\epsilon)$ is actually a neighborhood?

Comment: @ZhengLiu I guess it's a matter of experience. At first, one needs to look at the definitions and write it all down, but after some time one has enough experience with initial topologies - or at least the subset of initial topologies that are weak topologies on topological vector spaces - that one immediately sees/knows it. Note that $$N(f_1,\dotsc,f_n;\epsilon)=N(f_1;\epsilon) \cap\dotsc\cap N(f_n;\epsilon),$$ so by the finite intersection property of neighbourhoods, it suffices to see that $N(f;\epsilon)$ is a neighbourhood of $0$. But $N(f;\epsilon)=f^{-1}(\{z:\lvert z\rvert < \epsilon\})$.

Comment: And since $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < \epsilon\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ resp. $\mathbb{R}$, the continuity of $f$ (in the weak topology) shows that $N(f;\epsilon)$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in the weak topology.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I see my problem now. I mis-understood the definition of the weak topology. I thought a set $U$ is open only if for every functional $f$, there must be an open set $V_f$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $U=f^{-1}(V_f)$. I think this is far too weak that even $N(f;\epsilon)$ may not belong to this "topology". Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Ah. That can't work out, since we have the zero functional $\zeta$, and $\zeta^{-1}(V)$ is always either $\varnothing$ (if $0 \notin V$) or the whole space. You choose _some_ (finitely many) functionals and corresponding open sets, and take the intersection, but that doesn't give you all open sets, only a basis of the weak topology. But generally, when dealing with topological vector spaces and linear functionals, it is better to focus on neighbourhoods of $0$ than on general open sets.

Comment: Ah. Yes. zero functional is very nice extreme example. After realizing this, the $N(f_1,\dotsb, f_n; \epsilon)$ becomes fairly natural. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

We're considering finite subsets of the dual space, which are less general than bounded subsets. The basis by the latter contain the former and hence this gives the weakest topology. Since we're interested in the weakest topology where the functionals are continuous (hence bounded), it makes sense to consider finite subsets of the dual space.